# Can someone explain why the Django button.theme_toggle does not work in Chrome? Edge is ok

Tags: django, django-templates

[image]

Why does this control not work?

It works properly with Edge browser, not Chrome.

Comment: Maybe try to clear your cache if you upgraded recently.

Comment: I'm seeing the same. I recently updated from django 4.1.9 to 4.2.3. I have cleared my cache and it doesn't work in Edge or in Chrome. Did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case CTRL+F5 did the job